# Incorporating touch-free gestures into my Android application

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an Android app and I'd like the camera to recognize when the user makes a gesture in front of the 
camera with their hand.
I was considering opening up the camera and creating a direction vector based on the direction in which someone gestures in front of the camera. 
I'm not quite sure how to implement this though. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant "touch-free gestures". So the user could wave their hand in front of the camera, for example. I've updated the question to reflect this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered the HandWave library? I haven't personally used it, but it might be a good option. There are a few examples online using the library that look pretty helpful.

Comment: Hi there, do you have any more details about HandWave?

Comment: I've only used it for one project, but the library worked pretty well for me. Here's a link to the main github page: https://github.com/kritts/HandWave
There are a few examples on there as well - which are super helpful in my opinion.